# Poisson State Space with AR(1) latent process

Tags: r, categorical-data, poisson-distribution, state-space-models

I have been trying to use [sspir](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sspir/index.html) R package to estimate the following Poisson model:

$Y_{t}\sim Po(\exp(\lambda_{t}));$ such that $\lambda_{t}=X_{t}\beta
+\gamma_{t}$ and $\gamma_{t}=\theta\gamma_{t-1}+u_{t},u_{t}\sim NID(0,\sigma
^{2}).$

In State-space form, we have $\lambda_{t}=Z_{t}F_{t},$ $Z_{t}=\left[
X_{t}\: 1\right]  ,$ $F_{t}=\left[  \beta^{\prime}\: \gamma_{t}\right]
$

Then, $F_{t}=\left(
\begin{array}
[c]{ll}%
1 & 0\\
0 & \theta
\end{array}
\right)  F_{t-1}+\left(
\begin{array}
[c]{l}%
0\\
u_{t}%
\end{array}
\right)  $. Standard initial conditions are also set.

I have been trying to use `sspir` package in R to estimate this model, but I was not able to. If I let $\gamma_{t}$ to be a random walk, then it is standard.

Any suggestion? I am kind of new with this models so any help is very much appreciated.